# Как сделать единый контейнер в gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

ситуация такая,что вынуждены переезжать с jenkins на gitlab ci. Каждый раз когда происходит этап в пайплайне, то создаётся новый контейнер, хотелось бы узнать можно ли сделать так,чтобы контейнер использовался предыдущий, то есть единый. Executer стоит docker

Comment: `команда1 && команда2`. или `команда1; команда2`, если не важен код возврата первой команды.